# Change copyDown() Script to operate on just one Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

In Google Sheets I have a sheet with Form Responses, and to the right of the form columns I have columns with formulas that use form data for functions.

At the start I had the formulas extended down the rows so they worked on new form submissions, but found that new form submissions would clear the row out :(.

Instead of manually extending formulas down after each submission I installed [Andrew Stillman's `copyDown()` script](http://pastebin.com/1BaE1v9p); what it does is copies down the formulas after scripts are submitted.

Now the problem I'm having is that the script works when run manually, but when I set to trigger on form submits it copies the said formula on that sheet **and** on all other sheets in the spreadsheet. I Do Not Want that side-effect, as it messes the whole spreadsheet up. :((

What I thought to do is edit script so it only works on the one Form Response sheet, not all sheets. But I don't know how to do that.

The name of the sheet I want it to run on is "Requests", and the `gid=8`.

How do I edit this script to only work for that one sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get code to run on just a particular sheet use the .getSheetByName() method. For example:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var reqSh = ss.getSheetByName('Requests');
```

There is another way that might be easier. You could try keeping one sheet purely for form submissions and use an arrayformula in a second sheet to copy any values from the first sheet to the same range in the second.

=ARRAYFORMULA('Requests'!A1:H) would copy columns A to H.

I had the same problem as you and this was the solution. I placed my formulas in the second sheet in the columns to the right of the range and copied them down in the normal way. The formulas referred to the copied range in the second sheet. It worked a treat.

I didn't come up with the idea myself - I'm sure it was suggested by someone on the Google spreadsheet forum. I should give you a link to the post but I just looked and I can't find it.

Comment: Wow thanks.. I was looking for something like that too as another solution, I knew it was arrayformula.. but didnt kno it was that simple lol :P.Imma try script edit 1st tho since I already have it set to that

Comment: Glad to help and thanks for the best answer vote... but maybe in that case you should give it to Serge rather than me because he provided the script solution you asked for. :)

Comment: Im gonna use array solution instead since.. can't get script to work.. so this is best answer

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have (comments in code)

```
 var sheets = ss.getSheets() [8]; // you choose sheet [8]
 var cellAddresses = new Object();
  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) { // but you enter a for loop that adresses every sheet in turn...
    var range = sheets[i].getDataRange();
```

You should simply suppress this loop and use only the sheet number you want to be proceeded ...

The simplest way could be to do it like this :

```
 var i = 8
 var sheets = ss.getSheets() [i];
 var cellAddresses = new Object();
    var range = sheets[i].getDataRange();
  ...
```

and at the end of the loop delete the } that fitted the `for` loop

**EDIT** : the new code should be like this :

```
function copydown() {
  setCopyDownUid();
  setCopyDownSid();
  logCopyDown();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets() [8];
  var cellAddresses = new Object();
  var i=8
//  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    var range = sheets[i].getDataRange();
    var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
    var values = range.getValues();
    for (var j=0; j<values.length; j++) {
      for (var k=0; k<values[j].length; k++) {
        var test = values[j][k].toString();
        var start = test.indexOf("copydown");
          if (start == 0) {
            start = start+10;
            var end = test.length-2;
            var length = end-start;
            var value = test.substr(start, length);
            var col = k+1;
            var nextRow = j+2;
            var numRows = lastRow-(nextRow-1);
            if (numRows>0) {
              var destRange = sheets[i].getRange(nextRow, col, numRows, 1);
              destRange.clear();
              var newLastRow = sheets[i].getDataRange().getLastRow();
              var newNumRows = newLastRow-(nextRow-1);
              var newDestRange = sheets[i].getRange(nextRow, col, newNumRows, 1);
              var cell = sheets[i].getRange(nextRow-1, col);
              cell.setFormula(value);
              cell.copyTo(newDestRange);
            }
            var cellAddress = cell.getA1Notation();
            cellAddresses[cellAddress] = test;
          }
      }
    }
    Utilities.sleep(500);
    resetCellValues(cellAddresses, sheets[i]);
  }
//}
```

Comment: ill give it a shot, other code fullofgas wasn't making the script work but I did like his array solution which Ill use if all else fails.

Comment: part concerning loop a bit confusing tho

Comment: I tried.. idk I got error.. I put in the code in 2nd box.. and delete } at end.. it saved but running it gave me error :/

Comment: You have to care which } you remove, if you look in the editor the } are highlighted by pairs when your cursor is on the first }, you cannot miss it

Comment: I copied it over .. tried to manual refresh function and got this
"Script copydown experienced an errorDismiss"

Comment: I got email about the error
 ReferenceError: "Requests" is not defined. (line 23)

Comment: I can't find anything called 'Reuest' in the code you showed...what happened when you run the script from the editor ? If you switched to the other solution I hope you get it all working. Please consider to update this post to keep us informed...

Comment: oops, sorry, typo in last post : I meant 'Requests' of course